# How to have accordion type of menu?

Tags: jquery

I'm creating a folder view type of plugin and i've put my code in jsfiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/masnR/1/
Basically i'm trying to have accordion type in this...

When i click on Folder2, folder1 should collapse and only folder2 should be visible and expanded.

How can i go ahead with this.. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Before I give you the solution

I can tell you right now, your HTML structuring is not very consistent Mr/Mrs!

Your top node link is not contained in an `li` and is treated differently. All nodes should have the same structure for easy traversing.

I would urge you to consider using a classic setup that looks like this

```
<div class='container'>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href='#'>Folder 1</a>
            <ul>
                <li>Sub item 1</li>
                <li>Sub item 2</li>
                <li>
                    <a href='#'>Sub Folder 1</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Sub item 1</li>
                        <li>Sub item 2</li>
                        <li>Sub item 3</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <!-- ... -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is much more consistent, and it is easier to traverse... also it is very aesthetically pleasing... ;)

Your javascript code is inefficient. Instead of collapsing each `li`, consider collapsing the `ul` instead. I also had a hard time deciphering what the code was trying to do, as I believe everyone has, which is why you haven't gotten many answers.
Consider adding comments or making your code "cleaner" to look at. It is for everyone's sake, including your own.

---

### Example

I have created [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/kGcfC/) for you to take a look at. These menus are very common, so you can expect many other plugins to have a similar markup/functionality.

It utilizes the same HTML structure as previously mentioned.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/kGcfC/) | Code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.fileview').fileview({
        bAnimate: false //I don't like animations to be honest ;)
    });
});

$.fn.fileview = function(options) {
    var config = {
        sCollapseClass: "collapse",
        sUncollapseClass: "uncollapse",
        sSelectedClass: "selected",
        bCollapseAll: true,
        bCollapseAdjacent: true,
        bStartCollapsed: true,
        bAnimate: true,
        iAnimationTime: 250
    };

    $.extend(config, options);

    //Collapse link & list
    function collapse($link, $list){
        //Remove the uncollapse class and add the collapse class to link and list
        $($link).removeClass(config.sUncollapseClass)
                .addClass(config.sCollapseClass);
        $($list).removeClass(config.sUncollapseClass)
                .addClass(config.sCollapseClass);

        //Animate?
        if(config.bAnimate){
            $list.slideUp(config.iAnimationTime);
        }else{
            $($list).hide();  
        }

        //Collapse nested lists?
        if(config.bCollapseAll){
            $("ul."+config.sUncollapseClass, $list).each(function(){
                collapse($(this).prev(), $(this));
            });
        }
    }

    //Uncollapse link & list
    function uncollapse($link, $list){

        //Remove the collapse class and add the uncollapse class to link and list
        $link.removeClass(config.sCollapseClass)
             .addClass(config.sUncollapseClass);
        $list.removeClass(config.sCollapseClass)
             .addClass(config.sUncollapseClass);

        //Animate?
        if(config.bAnimate){
            $list.slideDown(config.iAnimationTime);
        }else{
            $list.show();
        }

        //Collapse adjacent nodes?
        if(config.bCollapseAdjacent){
            $link.closest("li").siblings("li").each(function(){
                collapse($(this).children(":nth-child(1)"), $(this).children(":nth-child(2)"));
            });
        }  
    }

    //Select node
    function select(link, context){
        if(config.sSelectedClass == "" || $(link).hasClass(config.sSelectedClass)) return;

        $("."+config.sSelectedClass, context).removeClass(config.sSelectedClass);
        $(link).addClass(config.sSelectedClass);
    }

    //Start collapsed?
    if(config.bStartCollapsed === true){
        $("a, ul", $(this).children()).each(function(){
            if(!$(this).hasClass(config.sUncollapseClass))
                $(this).addClass(config.sCollapseClass);
        });
    }else if(config.bStartCollapsed === false){
        $("a, ul", $(this).children()).each(function(){
            if(!$(this).hasClass(config.sCollapseClass))
                $(this).addClass(config.sUncollapseClass);
        });
    }

    //Hide collapse class list nodes
    $("ul."+config.sCollapseClass, this).hide();

    this.each(function(){
        var _self = this;

        //Collapse/Uncollapse for list items that have a ul child
        $("li > ul", this).each(function(){
            var $_this = $(this),
                $link = $(this).siblings("a");

            $link.click(function(){
                if($_this.hasClass(config.sCollapseClass)){
                    uncollapse($link, $_this);
                }else{
                    collapse($link, $_this);
                }
            });
        });

        //Select event
        $("a", this).click(function(){
            select(this, _self);
        });

    });    
};
```

---

### The solution

There seem to be other issues with your code, but this is how I'd do it with the current markup.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Megst/) | Code

```
function showElement(element){
    element.addClass(config.collapseElementClass);
    element.removeClass(config.expandElementClass);
    element['siblings']()[displayEffectShow]();
    element.html(htmlCollapse);

    //Select all the li siblings
    var $siblings = element.closest("li").siblings("li");

    //Check if there were no siblings, which would indicate that we're at the top node
    if($siblings.length == 0)
        $siblings = element.closest("ul").siblings("ul");

    //Hide all the siblings
    $siblings.each(function(){
        hideElement($("a", this));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The accordion animation effect can be made with a [slideUp](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) and a [slideDown](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/). Both are supported by jQuery. But it's easier to use [jQuery accordion](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion).